# Kinesis client library record processor failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kcl

According to [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-failover-recovery.html):

> The worker invokes record processor methods using Java ExecutorService tasks. If a task fails, the worker retains control of the shard that the record processor was processing. The worker starts a new record processor task to process that shard. For more information, see Read Throttling.

According to [another page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/troubleshooting-consumers.html#w2ab1c12b9c11b5) on AWS docs:

> The Kinesis Client Library (KCL) relies on your processRecords code to
>   handle any exceptions that arise from processing the data records. Any
>   exception thrown from processRecords is absorbed by the KCL. To avoid
>   infinite retries on a recurring failure, the KCL does not resend the
>   batch of records processed at the time of the exception. The KCL then
>   calls processRecords for the next batch of data records without
>   restarting the record processor. This effectively results in consumer
>   applications observing skipped records. To prevent skipped records,
>   handle all exceptions within processRecords appropriately.

Aren't these 2 contradictory statements? One says that record processor restarts and another says that the shard is skipped.
What does KCL exactly do when a record processor fails? How does a KCL worker comes to know if a record processor failed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on my experience writing, debugging, and supporting KCL-based applications, the second statement is more clear/accurate/useful for describing how you should consider error handling.

First, a bit of background:

- KCL record processing is designed to run from multiple hosts. Say you have 3 hosts and 12 shards to process - each host runs a single worker, and will own processing for 4 shards.
- If, during processing for one of those shards, an exception is thrown, KCL will absorb the exception and treat it as if all records were processed - effectively "skipping" any records that weren't processed.

  - Remember, this is your code that threw the exception, so you can handle it before it escapes to KCL
- When KCL worker itself fails/is stopped, those shards are transferred to another worker. For example, if you scale down to two hosts, the 4 shards that were being worked by that third worker are transferred to the other two.

The first statement is trying (not very clearly) to say that *when* a KCL task fails, that *instance* of the worker will keep control of the shards it's processing (and not transfer them to another worker).